# Display xml content in jsp page

Tags: xml, jsp

Below is the body of jsp page i am using:

```
<body>
    <%


     String schema=(String)request.getAttribute("schema");
    if(schema!=null)
    {


    **out.println(schema);**
    }
    else
    out.println("no schema found");

    %>
    </body>
```

"out.println();"
 is not displaying the xml content in browser.

the content of shcmea is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" targetNamespace="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_DataTypes.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_Internal_DataTypes.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="RET_MAIL">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Represents the eddbdsbatch request for RET_MAIL</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AccountNumber">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="cType">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="CtypeType">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="RET_MAIL"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="RequestId">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                            <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,9}"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingId" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingRegion" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="P"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="N"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="W"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillIndicator" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="LS"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="75"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AccountBalance" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillAmount" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="DateLastchecked" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:pattern value="((0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d) ((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="PaymentDueDate" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DateType"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ctn">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="ContactNumberType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AlternateCTN" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AltPhoneExtension" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="CustomerType">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="R"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="clientIndicator" use="required">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="ClientIndicatorType">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Wireless_BDS"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="OverridePriorityString" use="optional">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="Languageid" use="optional">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="EN"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="ES"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Myconcern is how can i display the content of schema variable which is xml  in my browser?

Comment: I was trying to mark out.println bold when posting the question here. ** is because of that .

Comment: There is no valid HTML(like <p>,<h>) in your xml. so your browser ignores them.

Comment: yes . how can i get it displayed  then?

Comment: Show us how u're forwarding request to jsp? There are tutorials available for this topic

Comment: request.setAttribute("schema", obj.getSchema());
   RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
   view.forward(request, response);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop using scriptlets in your JSPs. Learn how to use the [JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Once that is done, use the JSTL `<c:out>` tag, which escapes special characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, `"` and `'` so that they appear correctly in the page and are not interpreted as incorrect HTML markup by the browser. Your code will simply become:

```
<body>
    <c:out value="${schema != null ? schema : 'no schema found'}"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i have included JSTL jar in my classpath and used <c:out> and it worked.

Comment: In my case it printed only values of XML tag. It did not print XML tags. Why so ? Any other setting needed ?

Comment: @KaushikLele ask your own question, with all the necessary details and explanations (inputs, outputs, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet Question is exactly same. So no need to duplicate it.  XML for your reference   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results>
    <status>OK</status>
    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>
    <url/>
    <language>english</language>
    <category>recreation</category>
    <score>0.0708333</score>
</results>

Comment: I realized that <c:out> is not being recognized. So I added <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> After adding it (and adding supporting jar jstl-1.2.jar) it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
```

in your jsp page,it won;t parse the XML & will display it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try `URLEncoder.encode`.

You need this: `<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>`

Then you can do: `URLEncoder.encode(schema)`.

---

My situation was calling a jsp as an endpoint for a web application. I wanted to send `http://host.com/getFile?path=path\text.xml` and I expected the contents of `text.xml` to be returned. However I was getting blank spaces.

I later realized this is because stuff like `<` makes the jsp think the String is jsp instructions. Instead, by wrapping the text in URLEncoder.encode(), it treated it as text that needs to be printed.

Then on the js side, I used `decodeURIComponent(val).replaceAll('+',' ')` (because it wouldn't be java without being a total pain) to decode the message, then I get a string that I can display in a textarea or whatever.

Answer (score -2):

JSP automatically parse the XML. So you need to change the content type of the jsp. Please use this..<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>

Comment: There is the same answer that was posted one year ago.

Answer (score -2):

Let me tell you the scenario:
I have one jsp page where I am searching the data and getting the XML value and other data in the same JSP page, when user select any row then xml value should be display in new window....
I am seeing that I am getting the XML value(I hidden it in the jsp page) in the page but when I pass it in the JavaScript function to open in the new page then it does not work.......

example of XML:

Note-->I have to display the XML as it is with all the Tag and schema information.

Hope it clears the scenario...

Comment: Please give an example of your solution.