# JSP not showing the contents of an xml file

Tags: xml, jsp

I need to show the contents of various files: .log, .xml, .cmd, .wsf, etc. I'm trying to write one jsp to generically get a file and print its contents.

Here is my code

- only works for logs & cmds
- prints "String" many times for wsfs & xmls

```
inputStream      = new FileInputStream(file);
reader           = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String line      = reader.readLine();      

out.println("Log file: "+strPath+"<br>");  <--------- This works always



if (!file.exists()) {
  out.println("File does not exist");
} else {


  while (line!=null) {     

  
    out.println(line.getClass() + "<br>"); <-- Prints "String" for xml & wsf
    out.println(line); <---------------------- Sometimes prints a space for xml & wsf
    

    line         = reader.readLine();


  }


}

reader.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Is there something special I have to do for xml and wsf files? They are similar in that they both have ml descriptors like `<job id="script">`

---

I have seen this answer to a similar question, but I'm not sure how to get it to work in my inherited codebase (I'm just copying others' work).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298733/1152809

Comment: HTML and XML are similar but have enough differences that a library for one will not always work for the other.  XML does not require returns character to that may be why it is not working.  I prefer using a Powershell script to do parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `URLEncoder.encode`.

You need this: `<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>` at the top of the jsp.

Then you can do: `URLEncoder.encode(schema)`.

---

I wanted to call a jsp as an endpoint for a web application. I wanted to send [http://host.com/getFile?path=path\text.xml](http://host.com/getFile?path=path%5Ctext.xml) and I get the contents of text.xml back. However I was getting blank spaces.

I later realized this is because stuff like `<` makes the jsp think the String is jsp instructions. Instead, by wrapping the text in `URLEncoder.encode()`, it treated it as text that needs to be printed.

Then on the js side, I used `decodeURIComponent(val).replaceAll('+',' ')` to decode the message, then I got a string that I can display in a textarea.